# Perceive data from InfoPath Form Field before triggering Workflow

Tags: workflow, infopath

is there any possibilty to pull data from an InfoPath Form into my workflow before it is basically started? 
Since i want to compare a field (which is later stored as a list item) if there has been any change going on to its prior status..

I can't figure out a way to perceive this information out of my sharepoint designer environment :/

Comment: apparently there is a really easy way out. Since there is an action which can wait for a field change in current item my problem has been solved. Nontheless this action is not available through the ribbon buttons in the menu. You have to double-click in the sharepoint designer and enter some keywords for this action - and look at that: the action appears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there is a really easy way out. Since there is an action which can wait for a field change in current item my problem has been solved. Nontheless this action is not available through the ribbon buttons in the menu. You have to double-click in the sharepoint designer and enter some keywords for this action - and look at that: the action appears!